# Make a lot of colum in the same Line - Front End Bootstrap5

Tags: html, frontend, bootstrap-5

I try to get 10 colums responsive in the same line with Bootstrap 5. After 5 or 6 colums, they automaticaly return to the line.

If i use something like the class "col-1", they stop the "responsive" and don't use the full width of the screen (screenshot below).

Can you now the solution ? Thanks !

I use this (Multiplicate by 10) :

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class='card'>
       <div class='card-body'>
        <h5 class='card-title'>TITRE</h5>
        <p class='card-text'>TEXT</p>
        <p class='card-text'>text</a>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
          <div class='card'>
       <div class='card-body'>
        <h5 class='card-title'>TITRE</h5>
        <p class='card-text'>TEXT</p>
        <p class='card-text'>text</a>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
          <div class='card'>
       <div class='card-body'>
        <h5 class='card-title'>TITRE</h5>
        <p class='card-text'>TEXT</p>
        <p class='card-text'>text</a>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Screenshot for understand what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBXBg.png)

[With col-1 class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sYgE.png)

Comment: read the docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/#row-columns-gutters

Comment: I read this but is not that i want. The gutters is for the space between each column. I want to "force" 10 colums without return to the line

Comment: the row is made up of 12 cols, so how many cols, when the cols are more than 12, it will jump to next line

Comment: use ```<div class="col-1">```

Comment: Thanks Srushti, do you see my screenshot ? Now, they jump to the next line after 6 cols. How can i "force" for go up to 12cols ?

Comment: Correct with col-1. But not exaclty what i mean. Because when i use the class "col-1", they don't take the full width

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Ok  zerdox, i did. I added some detail and my screenshot (fiew minutes early)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use col-1 instead of col

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
            <div class='card'>
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <h5 class='card-title'>TITRE</h5>
                    <p class='card-text'>TEXT</p>
                    <p class='card-text'>text</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <div class='card'>
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <h5 class='card-title'>TITRE</h5>
                    <p class='card-text'>TEXT</p>
                    <p class='card-text'>text</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <div class='card'>
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <h5 class='card-title'>TITRE</h5>
                    <p class='card-text'>TEXT</p>
                    <p class='card-text'>text</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <div class='card'>
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <h5 class='card-title'>TITRE</h5>
                    <p class='card-text'>TEXT</p>
                    <p class='card-text'>text</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <div class='card'>
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <h5 class='card-title'>TITRE</h5>
                    <p class='card-text'>TEXT</p>
                    <p class='card-text'>text</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <div class='card'>
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <h5 class='card-title'>TITRE</h5>
                    <p class='card-text'>TEXT</p>
                    <p class='card-text'>text</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <div class='card'>
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <h5 class='card-title'>TITRE</h5>
                    <p class='card-text'>TEXT</p>
                    <p class='card-text'>text</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <div class='card'>
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <h5 class='card-title'>TITRE</h5>
                    <p class='card-text'>TEXT</p>
                    <p class='card-text'>text</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <div class='card'>
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <h5 class='card-title'>TITRE</h5>
                    <p class='card-text'>TEXT</p>
                    <p class='card-text'>text</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <div class='card'>
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <h5 class='card-title'>TITRE</h5>
                    <p class='card-text'>TEXT</p>
                    <p class='card-text'>text</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You will see proper divs in browser

Comment: No they don't use the full width. I try with the snuppet + browser. I add a screenshot in my post with "col-1" class

Comment: I find something better, not perfect for the moment but better :). I use a bootstrap table and i inlcude the card class in to the <td> of the table. Now i need to find a way for fixe the width and not have a scroll (left to the right).